# Navbar drop downs are not working in bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I created a drop down menu fro my navbar, but it is not working when I hover on it.

My Template,

```
<header id="header" class="sticky-header"  data-sticky-class="not-dark" >

        <div id="header-wrap">

            <div class="container clearfix">
                <div class="divcenter" style="max-width:990px;">
                    <div id="primary-menu-trigger"><i class="icon-reorder"></i></div>

                    <!-- Logo
                ============================================= -->
                    <div id="logo" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                        <a href="#" class="standard-logo" data-dark-logo="images/logo-dark.png"><img src="assets/images/SW-Logo-Final.png" alt="Canvas Logo"></a>


                    </div>
                    <span class="inputgroupcss col-sm-5" style="padding-top:12px;">


                                    <input type="email"  (keyup)="submit(button1.value)" #button1  class="form-control required email" placeholder="Search by Name or Email"
                                        style="height:38px;">

                                <div  class="col-sm-12 nopadding ">

                                <ul class="searchlist">
                                    <li *ngFor="let detail of details">
                                        <img [src]='detail.image' alt="profile_image" style="width: 35px;
                            height: 35px;">
                                        <a (click)="redirect()" [routerLink]="['/demo/user',detail.profilename]">{{detail.profilename}}</a>
                                    </li>

                                </ul>    
                            </div>


                        </span>

                    <!-- #logo end -->

                        <!-- Primary Navigation
                    ============================================= -->
                          <!-- <nav id="primary-menu" class="pull-left" style="margin-top:11px">
                   <form style="width:300px" id="widget-subscribe-form2" action="include/subscribe.php" role="form" method="post" class="nobottommargin">
                           <div class="input-group input-group-lg divcenter" style="max-width:600px;">
                            <input type="email" name="widget-subscribe-form-email" class="form-control required email" placeholder="Search by Name or Email" style="height:38px;">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" style="height: 38px;padding: 6px 16px;"><i class="icon-line-search"></i></span>
                        </div>
                    </form>     <div *ngFor="let id of ids"  class = "nopadding col-sm-12">
      <button class="badge notification" (click) = 'getRequests()'>
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></span>
 </button>
         <span class="noti">   {{id.sent_id}}</span>    
 </div> 
                </nav> -->
                    <nav id="primary-menu" class="dark">

                        <ul>
                            <li class="onhovercolor">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div>srilatha mattepu</div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li id="top-cart" class="onhovercolor notopmargin noleftpadding" *ngFor="let id of ids"><a href="#" class="noleftpadding" id="top-cart-trigger"><i class="icon-email3" style="font-size:18px;color: #d35b29;"></i><span>{{id.sent_id}}</span></a>
                                <div class="top-cart-content">
                                    <div class="top-cart-title">
                                        <h6 class="nobottommargin text-center">You have {{id.sent_id}} Requests pending</h6>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 dropdownpanel">
                                        <h6 class="nobottommargin">Friend Requests</h6>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 dropdownpanel">
                                        <div class="col-xs-3 nopadding">
                                            <img src="assets/images/gallery3.png" style="height:45px;width:50px">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-6 nopadding">
                                            <h5 class="nobottommargin pendingnamescss">srilatha mattepu</h5>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-3 nopadding text-right">
                                            <a href="#" class="norightmargin button buttonwarning button-mini button-aqua" style="width:auto !important;">pending</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 dropdownpanel">
                                        <div class="col-xs-3 nopadding">
                                            <img src="assets/images/gallery3.png" style="height:45px;width:50px">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-6 nopadding">
                                            <h5 class="nobottommargin requestsnamecss">srilatha mattepu</h5>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-3 nopadding text-right">
                                            <a href="#" class="norightmargin button buttonwarning button-mini button-aqua" style="width:auto !important;">pending</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                </div>
                            </li>

                            <li class="onhovercolor norightpadding">

                                    <div class="downarrowcss"><i class="icon-caret-down" style="font-size:25px !important"></i></div>

                                <ul class="menu-pos-invert">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="/demo/profile">
                                            <div><i class="icon-user"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;My Profile</div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="/demo/settings">
                                            <div><i class="icon-settings"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Settings</div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="/demo/password">
                                            <div><i class="icon-settings"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Change Password</div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <div><i class="icon-off"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Logout</div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>

                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="onhovercolor hidden-sm hidden-md visible-xs">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div>srilatha mattepu</div>
                                </a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="/demo/profile">PROFILE</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/demo/social">SOCIAL ADDRESSES</a></li>
                                    <li class="list-borbtom"><a href="/demo/custom">CUSTOM INFO</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/demo/society">MY SOCIETY<span>(ALL)</span></a></li>
                                    <ul class="left-sub-list">
                                        <li><a href="/demo/personal" style="padding-left:15px" href="#">PERSONAL</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="/demo/professional" style="padding-left:15px" href="#">PROFESSIONAL</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <li><a href="/demo/requests">REQUESTS</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/demo/society">MESSAGES</a></li>
                                    <li class="list-borbtom"><a href="/demo/society">SOCIETY UPDATES</a></li>
                                    <li class="list-borbtom"><a href="/demo/search">SEARCH</a></li>
                                    <li class="list-borbtom"><a href="/demo/password">PASSWORD</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/demo/settings">SETTINGS</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" style="color:#ce5a2b;">LOGOUT</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" style="color:#ce5a2b;">Qr Code</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>


                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                    <!-- #primary-menu end -->

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </header>
```

I created a drop down menu fro my navbar, but it is not working when I hover on it.

Comment: That bootstrap Navbar Dropdown is working on click not on hover. So you have to customize your code for open that on Hover.

Comment: Clean up your code and create a minimal example.

Comment: Please create a [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net) and study [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please create a fiddle

Comment: Have you included bootstrap js?

Answer (score 0):

**First thing is that you have to use pure Bootstrap Navbar code.**

*and then simply add below Custom jQuery, and see magic your Drop-down will be open on hover of your parent menu link hover.*

```
$('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
}, function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
});
```

Please check attached [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Dynamic_Designer/oxm7zmaz/).

Comment: In mobile menu is not opening

Comment: It's just customized for the desktop version, not for a mobile.

Comment: and @Kabali FYI in mobile version it was not working just because of jQuery wrong listing like, by mistake, I was just put Bootstrap.min.js on top of jQuery.min.js